# How to save custom fields on comments?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code to save a comment from a custom form, via POST:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $time = current_time('mysql');

    $data = array(
        'comment_post_ID' => $_POST['comment_post_id'],
        'comment_author' => $_POST['author'],
        'comment_author_email' => $_POST['email'],
        'comment_content' => $_POST['comment_content'],
        'comment_type' => '',
        'comment_parent' => $_POST['comment_parent'],
        'comment_author_IP' => $_POST['author_IP'],
        'comment_date' => $time,
        'comment_approved' => 0
    );

    wp_insert_comment($data);
}
```

Everything is working fine, but how do I add a custom field to `$data`? My custom field is already created, and I'm using:

```
    update_comment_meta( $_POST['comment_post_id'], 'author_avatar', $_POST['author_avatar'] );
```

To register the author avatar on the custom field. But when the comment is saved, the field appears to be empty.

Does `wp_insert_comment` accept custom fields? Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not an expert in WP by any means but it looks by the documentation for that particular function it's hardcoded to accept just options it says it accepts. You could easily duplicated the function and make it your work as you want.

Comment: This looks like the correct way to go to me.

update_comment_meta returns a boolean value, what is being returned when you run the function? Are you sure the post value isn't empty?

Comment: @Rasclatt but I think that's why `update_comment_meta` was created. This function will allow updates on comment meta entry and is also used to create a meta entry. The problem here is I can't save this `$data` with the custom field included.

Comment: @Fencer04 The $_POST returns the values I need. Everything is being recorded on my database, only the custom field is ignored, probably because it's not inside the array. But how to make `wp_insert_comment` accept more data on this array?

Comment: You can add an item called 'comment_meta' to the $data and pass an array to that. Check this documentation to see what you are allowed to pass to wp_insert_data.

[https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_comment/](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_comment/)

Comment: @Fencer04 That's exactly what I needed. Please comment as answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an item called 'comment_meta' to the $data and pass an array to that. Check this documentation to see what you are allowed to pass to wp_insert_data.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_comment/